# Which library has Alachisoft.NCache.Linq

Tags: ncache

I'm trying to use LINQ search inside NCache. I don't like to use OQL search, but I could not find the reference to Alachisoft.NCache.Linq which I've seen in couple of samples and tutorial.

Can anyone guide me what library need to be included? I'm using developer version of Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Alachisoft support mail, the file resides in 
NCache installation folder. C:\Program Files\NCache\integrations\LINQToNCache).

Alachisoft blog and their website is not helpful to find answer for this question, which it should be. Lot of dead links in their active site.